# Does $\sum_{r = 1}^n \ln\left(\frac{1 + r}{r}\right) = \ln (\Gamma(n + 2)) - \ln (\Gamma(n+1))$? If so, why?

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function, telescopic-series, digamma-function

When attempting the evaluate the integral $\int_0^1 \{\ln(x)\}$, where $\{ x \}$ is the [fractional part function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part), I came across the following sum:
$$\sum_{r = 1}^n \ln\left(\frac{r + 1}{r}\right) $$
While the sum can be rewritten with the quotient property of the logarithm and telescoped to reach $\ln(n + 1)$, I came across, in a [Mathematics MI video](https://youtu.be/xt4NrcLeiww?t=338), an interesting alternative method. His argument (transcribed verbatim) is as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{r = 1}^n \ln\left(\frac{1 + r}{r}\right) &= \ln (\Gamma(n + 2)) - \ln (\Gamma(n+1)) \\ 
&= \ln \left( \frac{\Gamma (n+2)}{\Gamma(n+1)} \right) \\
&= \ln \left( n+1 \right)
\end{align}
$$

Is the first line of the equation valid? If so, where does the identity come from?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Same, but instead of telescoping, you add all summands that have a $+$ together and the ones that have a $-$ together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof:

$$
\begin{align}\ln(\Gamma(n+2))-\ln(\Gamma(n+1)) &= \ln\left(\frac{\Gamma(n+2)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\right)\\
&= \ln\left(\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}\right) \\
& = \ln(n+1)\\
 &= \displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{n}\ln\left(\frac{1+r}{r}\right)\end{align}
$$
$\blacksquare$